# Reload UIView With UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I need to reload (update) the self.view with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animation. Visually, old view animates with curl-up effect and new updated view is presented after it. I could not find a better approach than to create a current view's screenshot, place it on top of all, and apply animation to roll it up and remove. Then updated view elements would be nicely presented after old view curled up.

However, curl-up does not work. The transition becomes fade out rather than curl up. What's wrong? The code is below.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIView* screenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
screenView.tag = TAG_SCREENSHOT_VIEW;
screenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:screenshot];
[self.view addSubview:screenView];
[screenView.superview bringSubviewToFront:screenView];

[UIView transitionWithView:screenView
                  duration:1.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^ { screenView.alpha = 0.0f; }
                completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                    [screenView removeFromSuperview];
                }];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct version:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^ { [screenView removeFromSuperview]; }
                completion:nil];
```

transitionWithView is self.view and animation block should be removing **screenView**.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually fading out your view by zeroing its `alpha` within an animation.

Try adding the subview in the animation block (and only there) to get the view adding animated:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
              duration:1.0f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
            animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:screenView]; screenView.alpha = 0.0f; }
            completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                [screenView removeFromSuperview];
            }];
```

In any case, I am not sure I can understand what the `screenView.alpha = 0.0f;` is doing there. Possibly the following is closer to what you are trying to achieve (in this case you need to add the subview before doing the animation):

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
              duration:1.0f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
            animations:^ { [screenView removeFromSuperview]; }
            completion:nil];
```

Comment: Might be simpler to use + (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView... which updates the view hierarchy for you.

Comment: @danh: that's a very good option; though, I think what matters for the OP is seeing how to modify its own code to make it work. thanks anyway.

Comment: would that change not constitute a modification?  :-)

Comment: @sergio: thanks, I am trying though without alpha 0 the view simply disappears now and no visible animation is ever noticed. I'll play more to understand what's happening. Perhaps, method parameters are not correctly used?

Comment: @danh: I thought about that approach too but it would not work well visually. I want an old view to curl up and new updated view would be under it. So fromView would be the same as toView. I'd need to add extra layers to make it happen and I did not want to complicate things. Unless you think I am missing something?

Comment: Got it! **transitionWithView** should be **self.view**. Animation should be state: **[screenView removeFromSuperview];**

Comment: @Vad: yes, `self.view` is the animated view. you spotted it!